# PhP decode array send from android volley

Tags: php, android, arraylist, android-volley

Hi I have written a request using android volley to send an ArrayList of String value to PhP server. The server need to decode the JsonObject (which is and ArrayList) and using MySQL command to query database and return result related to any value within the ArrayList.

Here is my request code from android (to send ArrayList eventIDBeacon to PhP server)

```
private void getEventDetailRespond(RequestQueue requestQueue) {
        JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
        try {
            params.put(Config.EVENT_ID, eventIDBeacon);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Creating a JSONObject request
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,Config.DATA_URL,params,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject respond) {
                            try {
                                eventArray = new JSONArray();
                                eventDetail = new ArrayList<>();
                                eventArray = respond.getJSONArray("result");
                                eventDetail = getEventDetail(eventArray);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Toast.makeText(Beacon_MainActivity.this, "Unable to fetch data: " +error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                );

        //Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

    }

    private ArrayList getEventDetail(JSONArray j) {
        ArrayList event = new ArrayList();
        //Traversing through all the items in the json array
        for (int i = 0; i < j.length(); i++) {
            try {
                //Getting json object
                JSONObject json = j.getJSONObject(i);

                //Adding the name of the event to array list
                event.add(json.getString(Config.EVENT_TITLE));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Beacon_MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, event));
        return event;
    }
```

Here is my PhP server code to receive the array and using MySQL command to return the respond

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

// decoding the json array
$post = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);

$eventID = $post['EventID'];    

require_once('dbconnect.php');

$sql = "SELECT EventID, EventTitle, EventDesc, EventTime FROM Event WHERE EVENTID IN $eventID";

$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$result = array();


 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
        array_push($result,array(
            'EventID'=>$row['EventID'],
            'EventTitle'=>$row['EventTitle'],
            'EventDesc'=>$row['EventDesc'],
            'EventTime'=>$row['EventTime']
        ));
    }

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result), 256);

    mysqli_close($con);


}
```

I don't know why I did not get any result. Any help is much appreciate (I have try change manually the $eventID in PhP code to real value and it can send back the result)

Comment: Anyone can help? Struggle with this